# How to change UUID field representation globally in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, uuid

I have defined various models with `UUID` ids in a Django DRF project:

```py
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

However, the default `to_representation` implementation of `rest_framework.serializers.UUIDField` is:

```py
valid_formats = ('hex_verbose', 'hex', 'int', 'urn')

def to_representation(self, value):
    if self.uuid_format == 'hex_verbose':
        return str(value)
    else:
        return getattr(value, self.uuid_format)
```

So the output of all API routes in the project render the UUID output as a string, divided by dashes: `"id": "86582c7d-a10e-4e2e-be42-8e045ca0fa00"`, what I want to do is to change the global representation of UUIDs in all the project serializers/routes to hex (removing the dashes), `"id": "86582c7da10e4e2ebe428e045ca0fa00"`.

Does anyone know how can I address rest-framework to change the output for all UUIDs?

> I don't want to change any pre-defiend model, serializer or view!